# Google Analytics for Chrome App

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-analytics, google-chrome-app

**Situation:**

I want to track events from my chrome app that has the following URL

`chrome-extension://APP_ID`.

In Google Analytics webpage, the only supported protocols are `http` and `https`

[image]

I just entered a random URL for the Website URL for now. I also set my manifest properly:

```
"permissions": ["webview", "browser", "http://www.youtube.com/*",
  "https://www.youtube.com/*", "https://fonts.googleapis.com/*",
  "https://www.google-analytics.com/*", "https://ssl.google-analytics.com/", "storage", "notifications
 ],
"sandbox": {
  "pages": ["sandbox/sandbox.html"]
},
```

Then, from my app I do the following when the app starts inside a sandbox:

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://ssl.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-TRACKING-ID', 'auto');
ga('set', 'checkProtocolTask', null); // Removes failing 
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

**Problem:**

The analytics page doesn't show any events so I am assuming setting the default url properly might actually matter. What should I do to track events from my Chrome app?

**Update:**

I see that the following request fires.

> http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&_v=j41&a=1768111489&t=pageview&_s=2&dl=chrome-extension%3A%2F%extension_ID%2Fsandbox%2Fsandbox.html&ul=ko&de=EUC-KR&sd=24-bit&sr=1440x900&vp=300x200&je=0&fl=21.0%20r0&_u=SAEAAEABI~&jid=&cid=2006929393.1458033861&tid=UA-75139981-5&z=437206753'
>   -H 'Pragma: no-cache' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,ko;q=0.6' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
>   (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like
>   Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36' -H 'Accept:
>   image/webp,image/*,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -H
>   'Connection: keep-alive

Does this mean I am sending Google Analytics requests correctly? Should I wait a couple of days to see the first update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that currently [Apps documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/analytics) has a link to a special library, [Chrome Platform Analytics](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-platform-analytics), that takes care of most of the setup for you, bypassing the need for tricks like sandboxing.

However, for the most relevant part of your question - you're trying to create a wrong property type. Even though it's not intuitive, you need to [set up a Mobile App property](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2614741). There, you won't need to provide a URL. This is part of [setting up the above library](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-platform-analytics/wiki#prerequisites) as well.

Oh, and because the URLs are still "special", sending a `pageview` does not work for it. Using the above library, `sendAppView()` is the way to go; otherwise, you can always send custom events.

Comment: Hey @Xan, I am glad you answered because your previous answers to making chrome extensions was absolutely helpful. Let me add an update. Also, I use sandbox in my app anyway so I am fine with sticking the code inside sandbox. But I don't understand why I don't see the tracking results in my Google Analytics dashboard.

Comment: Try observing the realtime view.

Comment: I am looking at the realtime view but I don't see anything coming up. Do you have an idea?

Comment: I think that quite possibly `pageview` is an invalid event for Chrome Apps. Try a custom event, or, if you're using the library I'm mentioned, do [this](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-platform-analytics/wiki#track-app-view-changes). And make sure you have a Mobile App property.

Comment: That was it. Could you add that `pageview` doesn't work for Chrome Apps? I will accept your answer.

Comment: Hey @Xan do you think you can look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36121178/chrome-app-sandbox-resource-address-unreachable