# Chrome app: sandbox resource address unreachable

Tags: google-chrome-app

I am trying to set a webview's source using a local file.

**Manifest:**

```
  "webview": {
    "partitions": [{
      "name": "static",
      "accessible_resources": [
        "sandbox/sandbox.html",
        "sandbox/sandbox.js",
        "sandbox/sandbox.css",
      ]
    }]
  },
```

**Set Webview's source**

```
  var webviewSrc = chrome.runtime.getURL('sandbox/sandbox.html');
  //console.log prints chrome-extension://MY_CHROME_APP_ID/sandbox/sandbox.html
  webviewEl = <webview id="webview" ref="Webview" src={webviewSrc} partition="static"></webview>
```

**Error:**

```
<webview>: The load has aborted with error -109: ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE.
```

Why is it happening, and how do I fix this issue?

**This setting works:**

**/foreground/main.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./bundle/app.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./main.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>

    <div id="webview-container">
      <webview id="youtube-webview" src="sandbox/sandbox.html" partition="static"></webview>
    </div>

    <script src="./bundle/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**/sandbox/sandbox.html**

```
Hello
```

**This setting returns 'address unreachable' error:**

**/foreground/main.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./bundle/app.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./main.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="./bundle/app.js"></script> <-- initialize webview inside here
  </body>
</html>
```

**/sandbox/sandbox.html**

```
Hello
```

**/foreground/bundle/app.js**

```
var webviewSrc = chrome.runtime.getURL('sandbox/sandbox.html');
// or var webviewSrc = 'sandbox/sandbox.html';
webviewEl = _react2.default.createElement("webview", { id: "webview", ref: "Webview", src: webviewSrc, partition: "static" });
// ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

`<webview>` is for *external* content.

To [embed your own sandboxed pages](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_external#embedding_sandbox), use `<iframe>`.

Also, apparently it's important to use relative paths - `getURL` returns a different URI scheme from what's expected.

Comment: I want to use webview instead of an iframe because I need to modify its request headers. Webview that sourced a local file worked totally fine until after I restructured the directories a little. Could you please check my update?

Comment: Note that you used a relative URL before, and a fully-qualified one afterwards. Possibly that's the problem (full URL by `getURL` is not what's expected). However, note that the docs use `<iframe>`.

Comment: Does iFrame also support modifying requests' headers? On a webview, I can do webview.onRequest...

Comment: No, it doesn't support `webRequest`.

Comment: Do you know a way to debug this information? I tried using a relative url but it still returned `ADDRESS_NOT_REACHABLE`. Is there a way to see reachable addresses by a webview?